# Не удается составить sql-запрос

Tags: mysqli

Сам sql-запрос сейчас такой

```
SELECT `forum`.*, (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `tema` WHERE `tema`.`id_forum`=`forum`.`id`) AS `count_tema`,
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `post` WHERE `post`.`id_forum`=`forum`.`id`) AS `count_post`,
(SELECT `id_user` FROM `tema` WHERE `tema`.`id_forum`=`forum`.`id` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1) AS `id_user`,
(SELECT `login` FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id`=(SELECT `id_user` FROM `tema` WHERE `tema`.`id_forum`=`forum`.`id` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1) AS `login`
FROM `forum` WHERE `id_razdel`='1' ORDER BY `id` ASC
```

Явно не правильный, потому что не работает. Нужно составить запрос таким образом, чтобы вывести логин пользователя и время последнего сообщения, оставленного на форуме, таблица post. И все это дело передать в шаблон на Smarty. Кто-нибудь поможет?

Answer (score 1):

Проблему сам решил.

```
$req = $mysqli->query("SELECT `forum`.*, (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `tema` WHERE `tema`.`id_forum`=`forum`.`id`) AS `count_tema`,
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `post` WHERE `post`.`id_forum`=`forum`.`id`) AS `count_post`,
(SELECT `id_user` FROM `tema` WHERE `tema`.`id_forum`=`forum`.`id` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1) AS `id_user`,
(SELECT `login` FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id`=(SELECT `id_user` FROM `tema` WHERE `tema`.`id_forum`=`forum`.`id` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1)) AS `login`,
(SELECT `avatar` FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id`=(SELECT `id_user` FROM `tema` WHERE `tema`.`id_forum`=`forum`.`id` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1)) AS `avatar`,
(SELECT `time` FROM `post` WHERE `post`.`id`=(SELECT `id_user` FROM `tema` WHERE `tema`.`id_forum`=`forum`.`id` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1)) AS `time_post`
FROM `forum` WHERE `id_razdel`=".$row_razdel['id']." ORDER BY `id` ASC");
```